# How can I find my way out of a Jungle Biome?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was spawned in a jungle biome and tried to find cows, with my exploration I found 4 Modified and Normal bamboo jungles, a jungle temple, and A mesa biome with a modified badlands thingy. Reached the end if the mesa but at the end were just another jungle biome.

How do I get out?

Comment: That depends on the seed. Without that it's just a guessing game.

Comment: update I just found 2 more jungle temples and a tower with illagers and more mesa and jungle. For a journey to find a cow for leather.

Answer (score 1):

Take your compass(if you are returning to your base) and head in one direction. You will be sure to get out.

Answer (score 0):

The jungle is a hard place to trek in, but I'll try to help. You could just keep running north/south/west/east (press f3 to see where you are facing). Or, you can climb the vines on the trees and look for a way out.

Comment: F3 does nothing on Bedrock Edition.